# Pugi XML with relative path

Tags: c++, pugixml

How can I get pugi XML to find a file with a relative path.

My folders look like this

The XML file is located here

XMLConfiguration->_master_config.xml

Config->src

Here I put the code

```
pugi::xml_document doc;

pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file("../../XMLConfiguration/_master_config.xml");

std::cout << "Load result: " << result.description() << ", mesh name: "      << doc.child("mesh").attribute("name").value() << std::endl;
```

I get this when I run the code:

```
Load result: File was not found, mesh name:
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can always try:**

```
pugi::xml_document doc;

std::ifstream ifs("../../XMLConfiguration/_master_config.xml");

pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load(ifs);
```

**Edit:**

(although in my tests your method works fine).

Comment: I tried that way and the same error.  I am using GCC 4.9.0 and I just include the .hpp file.  Not linking to library.

Comment: Even putting the xml in the src folder and doc.load_file("_master_config.xml");  will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I did not copy my files over to the build folder.  After doing this, the above code worked.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this more? Which files you copied, and you copied it in build folder means exactly which folder?